# Slow Image Upload Speed In Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, performance, image-uploading

Good day, I am having some problems with the WordPress crunching all my images which really slows down the process of uploading images. Is there any way of removing the Flash Uploader. I have already added the following code to all the function.php files in my Cpanel:

```
add_filter('flash_uploader', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ), 1);
```

as well as

```
add_filter('flash_uploader', create_function( '$a', "return false;" ), 1);
```

I have also changed the media settings Image sizes all to 0.

Nothing seems to be working it keeps crunching the images when I upload it.
If anyone can help I will really appreciate it as this is driving me crazy now.

The internet connection speed is perfect 100mb per sec 
file size and resolution of the images are good
Hosting server is perfect as the other sites have no issues at all.
Also not the plugins as I have already checked them as well.

The internet connection speed is perfect 100mb per sec 
file size and resolution of the images are good
Hosting server is perfect as the other sites have no issues at all.
Also not the plugins as I have already checked them as well.

```
add_filter('flash_uploader', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ), 1);
```

File and image upload without anything crunching

Comment: what size images are you attempting to upload?

Comment: normal size 1920 x 1080 and smaller we optimize all images before uploading them